# bootstrap-select not working with ajax

Tags: ajax, vue.js, bootstrap-select

JavaScript:

```
var books = new Vue({
    el: '#book_app',
    data : {
        book_list : ''
    }
    created: function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '/admin/book/get',
            data: {
                member: memberCode
            },
            success: function (result) {
                this.book_list = result;
                $('#book_select').selectpicker('refresh');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
...
<div id='book_app'>
    <select class='selectpicker' id='book_select'>
       //each book object has 'name' and 'code' attributes.
       <option v-for="book in book_list">{{book.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
...
```

> I see all the books in `Network` tab in Chrome dev tool, also see all the `option` with book `name` in the `Elements` tab. But the options list doesn't appear in the web page.

Comment: can you share any jsfiddle or code snippet or any live demo so that we can reproduce.

Comment: also please try to remove this code `$('#book_select').selectpicker('refresh');`

Comment: @C2486 Because it didn't work so I added `$('#book_select').selectpicker('refresh')` and it still `fails`

Comment: can you share any jsfiddle or code snippet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) <- in reference to `this.book_list = result` in your `success` callback